# VisualStudio is showing 10,000 changes made and i'm not sure why. It just came randomly and its all from my C:\Users\mainuser

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-code

It says "Too many changes were detected. Only the first 10,000 changes will be shown below."

I tried adding a gitignore and removed all my repos from my computer but still no joy.

Any suggestions?

[Image from my side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQVY8.png)

Comment: Can you open the terminal, go to one of the folders involved and run this command: `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` and tell us what it says? It should show you the path to the root of the repository.

Comment: It says "PS C:\Users\abdullah> git rev-parse --show-toplevel
C:/Users/Abdullah     
PS C:\Users\abdullah>

Comment: That means you have created a git repository in the root of your users folder. This is probably not what you want or meant to do. Can you verify if this was intentional?

Comment: Not intentional at all. How do I change this?

Comment: If you are absolutely sure you don't need this repository, then find the `.git` folder in your `C:\Users\Abdullah` folder, and then delete that `.git` folder. Note, it might be hidden so depending on the tool you use to hunt for it you may need to show hidden items.

Comment: Thank you. It's sorted now, much appreciated

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are good duplicates here for this question so I won't leave a proper answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init+home , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+too+many+changes